# Windows phone 8 : Native c++ application development, what kind of c++ is this?

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8

I was trying to learn how to develop **c++** applications for **Windows phone 8**, but I encountered some kind of strange c++ syntax. For example defining a class was like this :

```
partial ref class MainPage : public Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Page… {…}
```

Or I think `^` is used instead of `*`.
I haven't seen these keywords anywhere . So what kind of c++ is this? And where to learn it?  Thanks.

Comment: Hope this will: help http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163681.aspx

Comment: That's microsoft's vision of "Native". I don't understand the reasoning, but they recommend writing logic in pure C++, and communicating with OS via these extensions.

Comment: That's C++/CX (WinRT), not C++/CLI (.NET).

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: The reason is that some of the OS modules are written with garbage collected languages, and C++ "normal" pointers don't interoperate with how the collector manage memory. The extensions you refer (essentially the /CX and /CLI) are the bridge between the  standard C++ and the "garbage collected world".  `^` is -in fact, interlally- a double indirection pointer, with the innermost one to be kept hidden and opaque.

Comment: @Emilion I am pretty sure that it could be abstracted in pure ISO C++